# spring-mock in production code

Tags: java, spring, jar

One of our applications has the `spring-mock.jar` in the ear. I am the CM and I'm not a developer, but it doesn't seem like you want mock services in your production application. I thought the spring-mock.jar allows you to mimic certain *services* while testing.

I see no code dependencies upon any of the classes in the `spring-mock.jar`, but there are always possible runtime dependencies that aren't compile time dependencies.

This organization collected about 160 jars and simply dumps them all into the classpath at compile time. They don't do a much better job when downloading them for ears and sars either. My job is to clean up this mess. I've found duplicate jars (i.e. different versions of the same jar file), jars that pretty much duplicate classes found in other jars, and even junit.jar in the ear and sar files.

So, is the `spring-mock.jar` a similar issue?

Comment: You definitely should not have mocks in your integration environment, so why not giving it a try removing this `spring-mock.jar` in the integration environment and seeing what happens afterwards. This way you won't be doing that directly on the production system.

Comment: Haven't got that far yet. I'm in the process of cleaning up. The _current_ system uses `<antcalls>` and  9 files Ant build files. Most targets are hit about ten times, and many are called up to 14 times. (And, they want to know why it takes so long). I've merged the build files into a single `build.xml`, removed the `<antcalls>` used `depends` parameter, and added Ivy. Build takes 1/5 the time despite Ivy downloading the jars. However, I have to _prove_ the process by duplicating the current output. Now, I've done that, I'm making notes of issues that the developers must clean up.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd give you credit, but you just put a comment. I'm just compiling a list of issues for the developers to _look at_. BTW, there's a problem of simply removing and testing in Integration. That jar might not be needed all the time. There might be a process that runs only once per month or maybe annually that requires that jar. Remove it, and everything runs fine until that process is executed. It's why removing junk is so difficult in production: No one knows exactly what's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you have access to the `Ant` build files I assume you can also browse through the source code.

In this case the easiest thing to do would be to run some automatic search on those text files for usage of `org.springframework.mock.*` and `org.springframework.test.*` (those are the packages I found in the `jar` file).

This way you can find how many places use the contents of `spring-mock.jar`. If all of them are located in the `test` directory, (differently put, the dependencies are only in unit tests) then you are on a safe side. If not, you would rather not remove this dependency from the class path.

Comment: I did that and used Tattletale. There is no dependency on spring-mock.jar in any production code or even the test code. I can also compile without spring-mock.jar being in the dependencies. As I said, it might be a runtime dependency. I'll give development the chance to answer with a scenario why mock would be used outside of the development environment, and even if it is used in a dev environment, why it should be included in an ear that will be used in production. I want an answer that doesn't involve the three words of "I", "don't", and "know".

Comment: If you are worried about the fact that some dependencies might be injected at the runtime, they have to be defined at some place as well (Spring XML files for example...), so scanning those files might be also helpful. I do not know whether this will allow you in 100% to answer the question whether this is not injected in some other crazy way, but it might lead you to being pretty damn close to this 100%.